# SForceAPI : unable to find classes listed on API? (Account, Contact, etc)

Tags: apache-axis, salesforce, webservice-client, force.com

API referred : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm
                         subsection: reference->standard objects

Client side details : **partner.wsdl, Axis2 1.5**, 
                                    generated stubs using unpacked option (-u).

I was hoping to find some basic objects like Account, Contact, etc (which were listed on above url) so that I can do something like

```
-> SObject[] sObjArray = queryResult.getRecords(); 

   for(SObject sObj : sObjArray){
     Account acc = [Account] sObj; 
   }
```

[used above approach successfully in another webservice - 'Zuora']

However, I could not find Account class in the generated classes. I guess I am into wrong approach, but atleast I should be finding the classes listed in the reference API.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partner WSDL has a loosely-typed data model that allows interaction with any organization's data without its schema being known in advance - you just get SObjects. In contrast, the **enterprise** WSDL is strongly typed, and has the Account, Contact etc types you are looking for - see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner.htm

Also, since you generate the enterprise WSDL on demand for your org, it includes your custom types (or objects, in Salesforce parlance).

[Updated to answer comment...]

I generated stubs with

```
wsdl2java.sh -uri ~/soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml -p com.superpat.partner -d adb -u -s
```

I'm not an Axis2 expert, but I hacked the following together and it seems to work:

```
package axis2partner;

import com.sforce.soap.partner.Login;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.LoginResult;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.Query;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.SessionHeader;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;
import com.superpat.partner.SforceServiceStub;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;

public class Main {
    private static String username = "user@example.com";
    private static String password = "password";
    private static String securityToken = "SECURITY_TOKEN";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // First, login to get a session ID and server URL
            SforceServiceStub loginStub = new SforceServiceStub();

            Login login = new Login();

            login.setUsername(username);
            login.setPassword(password + securityToken);

            LoginResult loginResult
                    = loginStub.login(login, null, null).getResult();

            // Now make a stub for the correct service instance
            SforceServiceStub serviceStub
                    = new SforceServiceStub(loginResult.getServerUrl());

            SessionHeader sessionHeader = new SessionHeader();
            sessionHeader.setSessionId(loginResult.getSessionId());

            // Now we can execute the actual query
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setQueryString("SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber, BillingCity,"
                    + " BillingState, Description FROM Account");

            QueryResult queryResult = serviceStub.query(query, sessionHeader,
                    null, null, null, null).getResult();

            SObject[] sObjArray = queryResult.getRecords();

            for ( SObject sObj : sObjArray ) {
                System.out.println(sObj.getId());
                for ( OMElement omElement : sObj.getExtraElement() ) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + omElement.getLocalName() + ": "
                            + omElement.getText());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In my dev org, this produces output of the form:

```
0015000000VALE3AAP
    Id: 0015000000VALE3AAP
    Name: United Oil & Gas Corp.
    AccountNumber: CD355118
    BillingCity: New York
    BillingState: NY
    Description: World's third largest oil and gas company.
```

NOTE - the raw SOAP interface is pretty generic, and not the easiest way to work with the Force.com API. You might want to take a look at the [Force.com Web Services Connector](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector). There is also a [REST API](http://developer.force.com/REST), but it is currently (Jan 2011) in developer preview, and not for production deployment.

Comment: Thanks, that was very clear. BTW, do you have any idea to re-implement the code snippet (in question) in such a way that it's partner.wsdl compliant.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the response posted by "metadaddy" and help out "Firefox" as well as the many others likely to stumble across this answer, I want to share some observations from personal experience:

1. It's very easy to use the partner WSDL from Salesforce.com (SFDC) with Axis (e.g. Axis 1.4), but it's very difficult to use the partner WSDL with Axis2 (e.g. Axis2 1.5.1 or 1.6.0).
2. To use the partner WSDL with Axis2, you would basically need to create facsimiles of the objects that are created from the enterprise WSDL. If you decide to use this approach, generate the stubs from the enterprise WSDL as well and use the code generated for "Account", "Contact", etc, as a starting point to create your custom "SObject" instances.
3. That said, my recommendation, simply, is to use the enterprise WSDL with Axis2. If you feel compelled to use the partner WSDL with some version of Axis, use it with the previous version of Axis.

A search on Google will show that many people agree with my assessment.

Better yet, though I've not used it, I'd recommend looking into using SFDC's REST API instead.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question... Take a look at the section starting here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_partner.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_partner.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: Thanks Andres, but the tutorial given is based on Axis whereas am using Axis2.